# Flutter - Get data using pushName

Tags: flutter

I´m trying to send data with pushName. Then i try to get this data to show in a Toast message.

**PushName**

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
                            context,
                            '/navigator',
                            arguments: <String, String>{
                              'instalation': widget.instalation,
                              'message': DemoLocalizations.of(context)
                                      .text('cancel-message') +
                                  " " +
                                  widget.datameterValue.toString(),
                            },
                          );
```

**Trying to retrieve data**

```
        class Navigation extends StatefulWidget {
          final ConnectionPage args;
      Navigation({Key key, this.message, this.instalation, this.args}) : super(key: key);
    }

    class _NavigationState extends State<Navigation> {
  void initState() {
      super.initState();
        print(widget.args); //NULL

    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
      content: Text(widget.args.messsage+ '.', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red[700],
    );
    key.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
    }
}
```

The problem: Return null.

So: What is the right way to get data using pushName? In the documentation show how can we get data [inside Scaffold](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments) but i need to get data in the initState.

**UPDATE**

**Routes**

```
routes: {
    '/login': (context) => LoginPage(),
    '/navigator': (context) => Navigation(),
    '/home': (context) => HomePageScreen(),
    '/connect': (context) => ConnectionPage(),
  },
```

**UPDATE 2**

I try something like this

```
 Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      '/navigator',
      arguments: Navigation(
          instalation: widget.instalation,
          message: DemoLocalizations.of(context)
         .text('cancel-message') +
         " " +
         widget.datameterValue.toString(),
     ),
);
```

Comment: Hi, can you include the code you use to manage the named route?

Comment: Update with routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in initState You need `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` and `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments` 
Demo pass `arguments: {'instalation': "123", "message": "456"}` 
You can see full code and working demo picture below

code snippet use push

```
    Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ExtractArgumentsScreen(),
                    // Pass the arguments as part of the RouteSettings. The
                    // ExtractArgumentScreen reads the arguments from these
                    // settings.
                    settings: RouteSettings(
                      arguments: {'instalation': "123", "message": "456"},
                    ),
                  ),
                );


@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      final routeArgs1 =
          ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
      final instalation = routeArgs1['instalation'];
      final message = routeArgs1['message'];
      print('instalation ${instalation}');
      print('message ${message}');

      key.currentState
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
    });
  }
```

code snippet use Navigator.pushNamed

```
return MaterialApp(
      // Provide a function to handle named routes. Use this function to
      // identify the named route being pushed, and create the correct
      // Screen.
      routes: {
        '/extractArguments': (context) => ExtractArgumentsScreen(),
      },

...

Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  ExtractArgumentsScreen.routeName,
                  arguments: {'instalation': "123", "message": "456"},
                );
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Provide a function to handle named routes. Use this function to
      // identify the named route being pushed, and create the correct
      // Screen.
      routes: {
        '/extractArguments': (context) => ExtractArgumentsScreen(),
      },
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        // If you push the PassArguments route
        if (settings.name == PassArgumentsScreen.routeName) {
          // Cast the arguments to the correct type: ScreenArguments.
          final ScreenArguments args = settings.arguments;

          // Then, extract the required data from the arguments and
          // pass the data to the correct screen.
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              return PassArgumentsScreen(
                title: args.title,
                message: args.message,
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
      title: 'Navigation with Arguments',
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            // A button that navigates to a named route that. The named route
            // extracts the arguments by itself.
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Navigate to screen that extracts arguments"),
              onPressed: () {
                // When the user taps the button, navigate to the specific route
                // and provide the arguments as part of the RouteSettings.
                 Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  ExtractArgumentsScreen.routeName,
                  arguments: {'instalation': "123", "message": "456"},
                );
                /*Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ExtractArgumentsScreen(),
                    // Pass the arguments as part of the RouteSettings. The
                    // ExtractArgumentScreen reads the arguments from these
                    // settings.
                    settings: RouteSettings(
                      arguments: {'instalation': "123", "message": "456"},
                    ),
                  ),
                );*/

              },
            ),
            // A button that navigates to a named route. For this route, extract
            // the arguments in the onGenerateRoute function and pass them
            // to the screen.
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Navigate to a named that accepts arguments"),
              onPressed: () {
                // When the user taps the button, navigate to a named route
                // and provide the arguments as an optional parameter.
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  PassArgumentsScreen.routeName,
                  arguments: ScreenArguments(
                    'Accept Arguments Screen',
                    'This message is extracted in the onGenerateRoute function.',
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// A Widget that extracts the necessary arguments from the ModalRoute.
class ExtractArgumentsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/extractArguments';

  @override
  _ExtractArgumentsScreenState createState() => _ExtractArgumentsScreenState();
}

class _ExtractArgumentsScreenState extends State<ExtractArgumentsScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  final snackBar = SnackBar(
    duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
    content: Text("message" + '.', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
    backgroundColor: Colors.red[700],
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      final routeArgs1 =
          ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
      final instalation = routeArgs1['instalation'];
      final message = routeArgs1['message'];
      print('instalation ${instalation}');
      print('message ${message}');

      key.currentState
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Extract the arguments from the current ModalRoute settings and cast
    // them as ScreenArguments.
    final routeArgs =
        ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
    final instalation = routeArgs['instalation'];
    final message = routeArgs['message'];

    return Scaffold(
      key: key,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(' ${routeArgs['code']} '),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Text('instalation ${instalation}'),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              key.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// A Widget that accepts the necessary arguments via the constructor.
class PassArgumentsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/passArguments';

  final String title;
  final String message;

  // This Widget accepts the arguments as constructor parameters. It does not
  // extract the arguments from the ModalRoute.
  //
  // The arguments are extracted by the onGenerateRoute function provided to the
  // MaterialApp widget.
  const PassArgumentsScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.message,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(message),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// You can pass any object to the arguments parameter. In this example,
// create a class that contains both a customizable title and message.
class ScreenArguments {
  final String title;
  final String message;

  ScreenArguments(this.title, this.message);
}
```

Comment: I updated the question. Can i do similar to code that i put on the update?

Answer (score 0):

So, I see you're using the simple `routes` approach.

In order to extract route arguments you need to supply an `onGenerateRoute` function to your `MaterialApp` (or Cupertino, I guess).

You can find an exhaustive example on how to do it [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments#alternatively-extract-the-arguments-using-ongenerateroute), so I won't crowd this answer more than that.

Hope this solves your problem, happy coding!

Comment: onGenerateRoute work in the MaterialApp and it's not that I need. The view that i need to retrieve pushName arguments is a StatefulWidget.